# Invalid method isRememberMeChecked

Tags: magento-1.9, login

in my website, in **template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml**, there's the following line:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me');
```

It calls the **template/persistent/remember_me.phtml** file. But the file content is not actually loaded at all.

I tried to insert the remember_me.phtml contents straight to the login.phtml file, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid method Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login::isRememberMeChecked
```

Why is this happening? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: did you enable the presistant from admin panel? To enable it go in `System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Persistent Shopping Cart -> General Options -> Enable Persistence`. Here, select `Yes` from select box and click `Save Config`

Comment: That was the problem. It seems that my theme loaded persistent templates no matter if persistent was enabled or not. Please post it as an answer so I can set it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable it go in `System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Persistent Shopping Cart -> General Options -> Enable` Persistence. Here, select `Yes` from select box and click `Save Config`